# Keep sound playing within the App but stop it when App goes to the background

Tags: android, audio, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, android-lifecycle

So I have a Sound I want to play continuously throughout the whole of my App. But as soon as the App goes to background, the sound should stop. I´m trying to do this during onStop(). The problem is that onStop() is called every time the activity is stopped, regardless of whether I stay within the app or not. Is there a way to differentiate between those cases? Something like this:

```
override fun onStop() {
    if [App is left but not destroyed] {
        super.onStop()
        mediaLength = mediaPlayer.currentPosition
        mediaPlayer.pause()
    }
    else { //i.e. activity is left but the new activity is from the same app.
        super.onStop()
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I tried to implement [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54433734/10858057), but had to translate it to kotlin. I think I did everything right, but I get an `unresolved reference: mediaPlayer` in the Lifecycleobserver.

Here´s the Observer:

```
package com.example.asdasd.soulfetch

import android.app.Application
import android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver
import android.arch.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent
import android.arch.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwner


class CheckLifeCycle: Application(), LifecycleObserver {
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this)
}
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
fun onAppBackground() {
    MainActivity.mediaPlayer.pause()
}
}
```

And here are the relevant parts of MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()

    fun playBordun() {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cbordun)
        mediaPlayer.isLooping = true
        mediaPlayer.start()
        }
    playBordun()
    }
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    mediaPlayer.stop()
    mediaPlayer.reset()
    mediaPlayer.release()
    }
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't gain such functionality using activity. Activity is highly prone to be destroyed, recreated. You should use Service to attain such functionality, as the service will persist, whether your activity is destroyed or not.

This [article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-song-playback--mobile-22778) is old and out of date, but can still learn using service with music from it

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use Service to play the sound now. I unbind the service onUserLeaveHint() and prevent the Unbinding in the Intent with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION. It works fine, so technically this is the accepted answer. My problem now is that I have the same problem as before, just in the new activity: When I use the Home Button there, the sound keeps playing. Any Idea how to unbind the service from the new Activity?

Comment: one option is, you can use listeners....when app goes to background, pause the sound via a listener

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom Application class (extends Application) and implement it with LifecycleObserver interface, and create a function within the CustomApplication class and annotate it with @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP) so when the app is in background the function will be triggered and inside it you will put the logic to stop the mediaPlayer (make it global to access it from different place whiting the app)

In order to use the LifecycleObserver you need to add LifeCycle to your app (it's an Android architecture component) here is the link:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **LifecycleObserver** to check whether the application in background or not.

```
public class CheckLifeCycle extends Application implements LifecycleObserver {

@Override
public void onCreate() 
{
    super.onCreate();
    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
public void onAppBackground()
{
    MainActivity.mediaPlayer.pause();
}

}
```

and add the class name **CheckLifeCycle** in a manifest

```
<manifest >
    ....
    <application
        android:name=".CheckLifeCycle"
        ......
    </application>

</manifest>
```

don't forget to include the basic Support library in gradle.

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to implement this, but get an `unresolved reference: mediaPlayer`. In MainActivity I do `lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer` and in onCreate I do `mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()` and `fun playBordun() { mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cbordun) mediaPlayer.isLooping = true mediaPlayer.start() }` Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: i can't understand. it seems everything fine in your code. would you plz give more details. when did you face this error?

Comment: I get warned about it when writing the code. Then when trying to compile it throws the same error: `C:\[path]\CheckLifeCycle.kt: (17, 22): Unresolved reference: mediaPlayer     > Task :app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug` To give more details I´ll have to ask a new question or try to answer this one. I´ll tell you here once I´ve done so.

Comment: I added some details to this question. See above.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Elam parithi 's answer, I made some modifications. This method can keep playing background music while switching activities within the app, and the music will be stopped when the BACK/HOME/MENU button is pressed or use gesture navigation (swipe from bottom to top) to go back HOME.

I create another class `BackgroundMusicService` using `Service` to play the background music.

```
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.os.Build
import android.os.IBinder
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi


class BackgroundMusicService : Service() {

    private lateinit var player: MediaPlayer

    val ACTION_STOP = "stop_music_service"
    val ACTION_START = "start_music_service"

    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bgm)
        player.isLooping = true // Set looping
        player.setVolume(50f, 50f)
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        if(intent.action == ACTION_STOP)
            player.stop()
        else
            player.start()
        return startId
    }

    override fun onStart(intent: Intent, startId: Int) {
        // TO DO
    }

    fun onUnBind(arg0: Intent): IBinder? {
        // TO DO Auto-generated method
        return null
    }

    fun onStop() {
        player.stop()
    }

    fun onPause() {

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        player.stop()
        player.release()
    }

    override fun onLowMemory() {

    }
}
```

In the `onAppBackground()` function, I use the code below to stop the background music. Switching the activities within the app doesn't stop the BGM. However, when exiting the app, the BGM will be stopped.

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
fun onAppBackground() {
    val musicIntent = Intent(this, BackgroundMusicService::class.java)
    musicIntent.action = "stop_music_service"
    stopService(musicIntent)
}
```

BTW, the including library should be the `androidx` package, because the `android.arch` package will cause conflict.

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
```

I hope this help.